# got an error Null reference exception was Handled

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, charts, mschart

I am trying to show the reporting chart by clicking  on the  one chart by using following

code but it was showing an error

ERROR : null reference exception was Handled
          Object reference not set to an instance of an object.                              at this line targetcontrol.ChartAreas.Clear();

and this is click event for chart control

```
 using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;


private void kpiChartControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Chart targetcontrol = null;
  Series series = null;
  Title title;
  string are;

  targetcontrol.ChartAreas.Clear();
  targetcontrol.Series.Clear();
  targetcontrol.Titles.Clear();

  DataTable accepts = null;
  accepts = KPIData.AcceptedvisitsByMembership(mf ,"accepted");

 are = " acceptedvisitsmshiptypes";
  targetcontrol.ChartAreas.Add(are);
  series = targetcontrol.Series.Add(are);
  series.ChartArea = are;

  title = targetcontrol.Titles.Add("Accepted Visits By MemberShip Type");
  title.DockedToChartArea = are;
  title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
  title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;

  foreach (Title titles in targetcontrol.Titles)
  {
    titles.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
  }


  foreach (Series serie in targetcontrol.Series)
  {


    serie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

    serie["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
    serie["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
    serie["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";

    serie.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;


  }
  foreach (Legend legend in targetcontrol.Legends)
  {
    legend.Enabled = false;
  }

  foreach (ChartArea chartArea in targetcontrol.ChartAreas)
  {
    chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
    chartArea.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 45;
    //chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = !overview;
  }

  targetcontrol.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(accepts.Rows, "mshiptypenumbers", accepts.Rows, "mshipType_Name");
  foreach (Series chartSeries in targetcontrol.Series)
  {
    foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
    {

      switch (point.AxisLabel)
      {
        case "Silver membership": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
        //case "Refused": point.Color = Color.Red; break;

      }
      point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}", point.YValues[0]);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: In which line do you get it ?

Comment: @Yochai Timmer targetcontrol.ChartAreas.Clear();   at this line

Comment: it does not showing any report ......... when i click one the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you get that error, you're declaring

```
Chart targetcontrol = null;
```

Then you're trying to use it without actually instantiating it to anything.

Comment: K one question I am using chart control to display the report it was showing the report thats fine when we click on the bar in the chart it has to show another chart .. My question is is there any event for clicking on the bar in ms chart to do something ....... I have seacrhed a lot but i didnot find any solution...

Answer (score 2):

You set a variable

```
Chart targetcontrol = null;
```

then trying to use

```
targetcontrol.ChartAreas.Clear();
```

targetcontrol is null and don't have ChartAreas property. Try change the third line

```
Chart targetcontrol = null;
```

to

```
Chart targetcontrol = new Chart();
```

Comment: K one question I am using chart control to display the report        it was showing  the report thats fine when we click on the bar in the chart it has to show  another chart .. My question is is there any event for clicking on the bar in ms chart to do something ....... I have  seacrhed a lot but i didnot find any solution...